# MimeMessage.writeTo(OutputStream) hangs

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to read through mails in a mailbox, but during parsing message content to MimeMessage, some particular mail makes the process hang, it doesn't show any error messages, the log shows the program stops at the step of MimeMessage.writeTo(OutputStream), below is the actual code

```
for (int n = message.length; i < n; i++)
            {Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "getMessages", "start convert");
                MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage)message[i];
                Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "getMessages", "A");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "getMessages", "B");
                msg.writeTo(bos);
                Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "getMessages", "C");
                bos.close();
                Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "getMessages", "start create bis");
                SharedByteArrayInputStream bis = new SharedByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
                MimeMessage cmsg = new MimeMessage(session, bis);
                bis.close();

....
```

below is the log information, it doesn't show any exception, but hangs at "B" which is at the step of "msg.writeTo(bos);" in the log

```
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     36:     [Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@d522e24d null
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     36: From address length         1
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     36: From address        INFORMATION <info@funds.com>
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     complete for loop j
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     start convert
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     A
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     B
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     C
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     start create bis
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     start cmsg to mimeMessage
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     content type: text/html;^M
        charset="utf-8"
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     37:     [Ljavax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;@9b58d2b8 null
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     37: From address length         1
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     37: From address        =?utf-8?B?6ZyN6bmD5Y6a?= <1757158944@qq.com>
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     complete for loop j
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     start convert
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     A
Mon Sep 10 09:44:41 UTC 2018    IMAPaccess      getMessages     B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I gave up to convert message type, if it hangs in conversion I directly let the for loop to skip and continue, so that some messages are omitted. I don't think it can be matter, because I find only spam emails can make the program hang. Below is the code

```
for (int n = message.length; i < n; i++)
            {   
                Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "getMessages", "start convert");
                MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage)message[i];

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


                // MJN1 has some SPAM email cannot be converted, so use thread to do the conversion 
                final Runnable stuffToDo = new Thread() {
                      @Override 
                      public void run() { 
                          try {
                            Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "run", "write to MimeMessage");
                            msg.writeTo(bos);
                            Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "run", "wrote to MimeMessage");
                        } catch (IOException | MessagingException e) {
                            Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "run", (new StringBuilder()).append("error = ").append(e.getMessage()).toString());

                        }
                      }
                    };

                final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                final Future future = executor.submit(stuffToDo);
                executor.shutdown(); // This does not cancel the already-scheduled task.

                // start the conversion and if the process hangs, the loop should skip and continue
                try { 
                  future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie) { 
                    Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "getMessages", (new StringBuilder()).append("error = ").append(ie.getMessage()).toString());
                    continue;
                }
                catch (ExecutionException ee) { 
                    Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "getMessages", (new StringBuilder()).append("error = ").append(ee.getMessage()).toString());
                    continue;
                }
                catch (TimeoutException te) { 
                    Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "getMessages", (new StringBuilder()).append("error = ").append(te.getMessage()).toString());
                    continue;
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    Log25.write("IMAPaccess", "getMessages", (new StringBuilder()).append("error = ").append(e.getMessage()).toString());
                    continue;
                }
                if (!executor.isTerminated())
                    executor.shutdownNow();

                bos.close();
```

I used thread and executor to make hang loop continue, and it's not a easy job.

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show when it hangs?  Perhaps it's a bug in your server.